# Browser compatibility for CSS @page rule

Tags: css, printing, cross-browser

I'm creating a TV weekly schedule for printing and I need more space in paper because of my large table. I found a CSS rule that helps you change the margin of pages in printing, like following example:

```
@page {
    margin: 0.5cm;
}
```

I'm wondering do all the browsers support this feature? And if they do, which versions?

And if they don't, is there any alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the compatibility report : http://www.browsersupport.net/CSS/@page

Looks like it is supported in most versions of Chrome and Opera, and Internet Explorer 8 and above, and current versions of Firefox.

Comment: I also found this page which is confusing me, take a look at bottom of the page!
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/@page

Comment: Good but what is the confusion?

Comment: @Yoda Your link says that firefox has support of this property since firefox 10 but mozilla says it's going to support `@page` after firefox 19.

Comment: Yeah, it says unknown in 10 for firefox, its only for a reference and I believe mozilla has more knowledge about its product as compared to third party resource...so it is up to you that which version you want to give support and use accordingly.

Comment: OP - From several sites it appears that it is supported on IE8+, Opera and Chrome (and taking what @Yoda has said)

Comment: @Yoda I checked it with my Firefox 18.0.2 and it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: @faridv as you said mozilla says 19.0 then it's good to go for other alternative if you really want to give cross browser support else use the same if you don't worry about it.

Comment: I always use [jqprint library](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jqPrint) to make any printing stuff works cross browser and u can also play with the css before calling a print method.